# Read the $_POST off a webpage

Tags: php, post

Is there a way that I can read the $_POST of a website that I don't own? For example I want to auto fill someone else's form for my users when they go there, so I wanted to reverse engineer their post.

Or is there a way to auto fill a form on someone else's form?

EDIT:
Some people asked what my motives are. I'm working with a group that doesn't have the right to change a website but wants more registration, and I wanted to see if I could remake the form so it was auto-filled to make registration easier.

Comment: you can't read their $_POST, but you can send them $_POST data

Comment: Can I reverse engineer it? e.g. know what they expect?

Comment: It's a valid question, why is this being downvoted?

Comment: You cannot prefill external forms (would be fun for writing exploits) but you can send a form to an external site with identical fields.

Comment: If that were the case, they'd be a lot of ticked off people (including myself). A Spammer's Paradise, it would be. So, what's the purpose for this?

Comment: I'd like to assume it's all theoretical. In short: no, you cannot. You cannot read `POST` data on a website you do not own.

Comment: Do tell as to what the purpose of this is. If you "know" the website's owner in question, good. Otherwise, I see this as being quite questionable in nature.

Comment: I'm working with a group that doesn't have the right to change a website but wants more registration, and I wanted to see if I could remake the form so it was auto-filled to make registration easier.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO, but, you can sniff the HTTP request.

See this question: [can-ones-post-request-data-be-sniffed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090959/can-ones-post-request-data-be-sniffed)

Basically, if it's a simple form, you don't need to read the post data, you can simply create an identical form with the same action url and set the method to post. You can auto fill this form and send it to a different site.

Comment: With the same action URL? The OP states *"Is there a way that I can read the $_POST of a website that I don't own?"* If the OP doesn't own it, then if the OP has direct contact with the person who does own it and agrees to use it with permission, then it could work, otherwise I see the OP's question as being quite questionable in nature. And if it does work, the whatever the Email recipient is set to, is another story.

Comment: The OP said "For example I want to auto fill someone else's form for my users when they go there" - in this case he can easy replicate the form in his own site (if that's his main purpose).

Comment: The OP hasn't responded to any of my comments, so he/she is either absent or ignoring them altogether. If "ignoring" is the operative word here, then he/she isn't bothering to defend him/herself with a valid reason. Anyway, that's "my" take on it. `$ignore="Guilty";` in my books, as goes for the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use FireBug or simply the browsers developer tools and analyze the network tab.

You should find all relevant information in the header section.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are built NOT to allow interaction between different sources, for example an iframe of site1.com inside site2.com can't communicate with JS.

Being able to read $_POST related to another site would be a security disaster. To assist the user the browsers utilize "auto-fill". That's all you get.

If it's a limited amount of peer-sites you may however contact the respective owner of the site and ask them to add support for passing arguments to their login(?) or registration(?) form, for example:

```
theothersite.com/register.php?email=theEmailYouKnow
```

By generating this link on YOUR server you get the email to popup on the other site IF implemented by the maintainer of the other site.